# Error: Compile Error: Constructor not defined:

Tags: unit-test

i wrote 4 test classes (StandardSetController ) two classes working fine

but remaining two are throw the above error error ( 4 test classes using same synatx)
please any body help me

Class :

```
public with sharing class ingController {
    public List<test__c >AllItest{ get; set; }
      public static String testid = '001'; 

    public ingController(ApexPages.StandardSetController sc) {
        if(ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id')!=null)
            Selected = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('id');
    }
     public PageReference Init() {


     }
}
```

test class

```
@isTest
public class ingControllerTest {

    public static testmethod void ingController(){
        test__c inv = new test__c();
        inv.name = 'test';
        inv.email__c = 'test@test.com';

        insert inv;
         ApexPages.StandardController sc = new 
                                         ApexPages.StandardController(inv);

        ingController Controller=new ingController(sc);
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your class constructor is accepting `StandardSetController` as parameter but in your test class you are passing in `StandardController`. if you align them it will fix the error.